# How to integrate TeamCity with Perforce Swarm test run status?

Tags: teamcity, perforce, swarm

Swarm can call a URL, and provide the changelist number and two callback URLs: one to report test failure and one to report success ([Swarm integration API](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/swarm/quickstart.integrate_test_suite.html)). Is it possible to integrate this API with Teamcity builds? Teamcity definitely supports remote runs for a given Perforce changelist, so the question is probably whether it can call back the provided URLs...

Comment: If you have Powershell V 3.0 or above installed on your build agents you could look at using Invoke-WebRequest (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) to call the remote URL.

Comment: Related issue in TeamCity tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-28423